# use concatenation in excel formulas possible?

Tags: excel, concatenation

is it possible to use concatenation inside excel formulas, similar as it is possible to concatenate variables with strings in vba?

suppose I have some values calculated

```
A1 = 1
A2 = A1 + 120   (equals 121)
```

now i need something like:

```
A3 = SUM("A" & A2)  (i want "=SUM(A1:A121)" )
```

it obviously works in VBA, is there a way to make it work in plain excel as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just use indirect

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A2))
```

so if you put this in (say) B1 and A2 contains 121 you get SUM(A1:A121)

(you wouldn't want to put in in A3 because you would get a circular reference).